# SQL query - how to limit number of rows per a specific column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to sample a group of products. Products belong to some Form. Form can be mapped to some catalogs.

For example, form=1523 is mapped to catalog =5 and catalog=8

I need to run on a specific form and to bring maximum 750 products from each catalog.

I thought of using limit (RowNum<=750*number of catalogs) but I don't understand how I can limit per catalog and not the total query result.

Also, I don't have a previous knowledge of how many catalogs there are in a specific form.

For example, lets say i want only 2 rows per each catalog. My sample is:

```
Product  Form   Catalog
-----------------------
1        50     5
2        50     6
3        50     6
4        50     6
```

How can I get a result of product 1 and 2 random products from catalog 6?

Comment: Your description is a little lacking, but can you use `LIMIT ??`somehow?

Comment: I will try to explain better. What you are saying (using limit) is exactly what i am asking (PLSQL is using RowNum) - how can i limit per catalog and not per whole answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the analytic function row_number():

```
select product, form, catalog from
( select product, form, catalog,
         row_number() over (partition by catalog order by product, form) as rn
  from mytable
)
where rn <= 750
```

The `partition by catalog` clause gets row numbers within catalog.  You need to put the `order by` clause in there too as I have, but you may want to order differently, that's up to you.